# Smallest Positive Integer Not Coprime to a Collection of Consecutive Integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, integers

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Define $f(n)$ to be the smallest positive
>   integer $m$ such that there exists a positive integer $k$ for which
>   $k+i$ is not relatively prime to $m$ for every $i=0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$. 
>   For example, $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=f(3)=6$, and $f(4)=f(5)=30$.  What I know
>   is that, if $g(n)$ is the product of all positive primes less than or
>   equal to $n+1$, then $f(n)\leq g(n)$ (and $k=2$ does the job in
>   getting $g(n)$).
>
> Is it true that $f(2k)=f(2k+1)$ and $f(k)\mid f(k+1)$ for every
>   $k\in\mathbb{N}$?  For all integers $n\geq4$, does $f(n)>n^2$ hold? 
>   What is the asymptotic behavior of $f(n)$?  <strike>If anybody proves
>   the assertion that $f=g$, then other questions are trivial.</strike>

**EDIT 1:** According to san's comment below, $f \neq g$.  What then is a formula for $f$?  If $h(n)$ is the minimum positive integer $k$ such that $k+i$ is not relatively prime to $f(n)$ for every $i=0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$, then do we have a formula for $h$?  Also, it seems like, for any $l\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)=f(n+1)=f(n+2)=\ldots=f(n+l-1)$.

**EDIT 2:** Let $p_i$ be the $i$-th smallest positive prime integer for $i\in\mathbb{N}$.  A conjecture by will is that $f\big(\mathsf{A058989}[n]\big)=p_1p_2\cdots p_n$ and $h\big(\mathsf{A058989}[n]\big)=\mathsf{A049300}[n]$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where the integer sequences $\mathsf{A058989}$ and $\mathsf{A049300}$ are found in http://oeis.org/A058989 and http://oeis.org/A049300, respectively.

Comment: $f(12)=2.3.5.7.11<g(12)$, take $k=114$ or $k=115$.

Comment: We also have $k\in\{2,2184,9440\}\implies f(14) = f(15) = \ldots = f(20) = f(21) = g(12) = 30030$.

Comment: @will we have 2201=31.71 so 2184 works only till 17.

Comment: Clearly only the odd k+i matter, since 2 will be always a factor of f(n), so f(2j)=f(2j+1).

Comment: @san Why is 2 always a factor of $f(n)$?

Comment: Brute force suggests $g(30)$ can cover 57 consecutive integers. Hope to calculate the reach of $g(36)$ later today.

Comment: Do you two (san and will) have a code that determines $f(n)$ and $h(n)$ for a particular $n$?

Comment: @will It seems intuituvely clear, but I have no proof.

Comment: @batominovski I have a sort of algororithm, wh$f(2p_k-1)\le 2.3.5...p_k.p_{k+1}$.

Comment: @san, how did you get that bound?

Comment: @batominovski the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A058989) implies that san's bound holds, and that it does not reduce to equality (as naive computations might otherwise suggest). If we conjecture $\  f(A058989[n]) = p_1\ldots p_n,\  $ then the corresponding $h(A058989[n]) = A049300.\  $ The OEIS mentions work done by Marty Weissman, Phil Carmody, and Max Alekseyev.

Comment: In OEIS it is said that Phil Carmody proved the bound, however, I couldn't find it. You take a positive integer $N$ such that $N\equiv 0\mod p_i$ for $i=1,\dots,r-1$, and $N\equiv 1\mod p_r$ and $N\equiv -1 \mod p_{r+1}$ (which you can by the chinese reminder theorem). Then 
$N-p_r+1,N-p_r+2,\dots, N,N+1,\dots,N+p_r-2,N+p_r-1$ yields a sequence of $2p_r-1$ consecutive integers which contain some $p_j$ as a factor, for $j=1,\dots,r+1$. You can also take $N$ with $N\equiv -1\mod p_r$ and $N\equiv 1 \mod p_{r+1}$ if that gives you a smaller number.

Comment: The proof of Phil Carmody is in https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/primenumbers/conversations/topics/117 it uses induction, I don't understand it fully, bUt I think I used similar ideas as his (to cover $\pm 1$).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the [Erdős-Rankin construction](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105477/what-are-the-limits-of-the-erdős-rankin-method-for-covering-intervals-by-arithme) shows that $f(n) \le O(g(cn))$ for any $c>0$.  With such an (asymptotically) large gap, it seems plausible that there might even be values of $f(n)$ which are not equal to some primorial.

Comment: Related question: [Smallest positive integer that is not coprime to any member of a set of integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269785/smallest-positive-integer-that-is-not-coprime-to-any-member-of-a-set-of-integers)

Answer (score 3):

Using Batominovski's notation $g(n) :=$ product of all primes less than or equal to $n+1$, we can show that $f(n)|g(n)$:

There exists at least 1 candidate pair, $m$ and $k$, for which each $1 < \gcd(k+i,m),\ \  i=0,\ldots,n-1.$ (Batominovski provides $m = g(n)$ and $k=2$.)

If $p^2|m'$ and $m'$ covers $k,\ldots,k+n-1$, then $m'/p$ also covers $k,\ldots,k+n-1$, and so every $m', k$ reduces to square_free$(m'),k$.

There is a prime $\  p' \le n+1\  $ for which candidate $m',k'$ satisfies $\  \gcd(m',p') = 1$, or the candidate reduces to the upper bound candidate, $m=g(n),k=2.$

Suppose we have reduced candidate $m'\not=g(n),k'$ with prime factor $p|m'$, $\  n+1 < p$. Because $n < p,\  $ there is (1) $\  j\in\mathbb{Z}[0,n-1]\  $ for which $\  1 < \gcd(\frac{m'}{p},k'+i)\  $ for all $i\in\mathbb{Z}[0,n-1]\setminus j.\  $ Because $m'\not=g(n)$ there is prime $\  p',\ \  \gcd(p', m') = 1,\ \  p' \le n+1 < p.\  $ Because $m'$ isreduced, we can also reduce $k = k'+d\frac{m'}{p}$ (for some positive integer $d$) $\to  \gcd(p',k+j) = p'.\  $ Then for further reduced $\  m= p'\frac{m'}{p}\  $ we have $\  \gcd(m,k+j)=p\  $ and $\  1 < \gcd(m,k+i)\  $ for all $i\in\mathbb{Z}[0,n-1].\  $ So the factors of every candidate $m'$ reduce to $\le n+1.$

I originally hoped a similar argument would reduce $f(n)$ to a product of the first ? prime numbers, but as yet we only have weak experimental suggestion of such a conjecture.

## Numeric Exploration

Considering each $m|g(n)$ and each $k=2,\ldots,m+1-n$ is the brute force way to find $f(n).\  $ My single-threaded, gcc, implementation ran sufficiently efficiently on my Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU G1840 @ 2.80GHz, for the following test cases, which strongly concur with san's bound:
$$ \begin{array}{rrrrc}
n & \frac{g(n)}{f(n)} & \frac{f(n)}{f(n-1)} & (k) & \frac{s(n)}{f(n)} \\
1 & 1 & 2 & (2) & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & (2) & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 1 & (2) & 1 \\
4 & 1 & 5 & (2) & 1 \\
5 & 1 & 1 & (2) & 1 \\
6 & 1 & 7 & (2) & 1 \\
7 & 1 & 1 & (2) & 1 \\
8 & 1 & 1 & (2) & 1 \\
9 & 1 & 1 & (2) & 1 \\
10 & 1 & 11 & (2) & 1 \\
11 & 1 & 1 & (2) & 1 \\
12 & 13 & 1 & (114) & 1 \\
13 & 13 & 1 & (114) & 1 \\
14 & 1 & 13 & (2) & 1 \\
15 & 1 & 1 & (2) & 1 \\
16 & 17 & 1 & (2184) & 1 \\
17 & 17 & 1 & (2184) & 1 \\
18 & 323 & 1 & (9440) & 1 \\
19 & 323 & 1 & (9440) & 1 \\
20 & 323 & 1 & (9440) & 1 \\
21 & 323 & 1 & (9440) & 1 \\
22 & 437 & 17 & (39470) & 1 \\
23 & 437 & 1 & (39470) & 1 \\
24 & 437 & 1 & (217128) & 1 \\
25 & 437 & 1 & (217128) & 1 \\
26 & 23 & 19 & (60044) & 1 \\
27 & 23 & 1 & (60044) & 1 \end{array}
$$

Here we have taken san's bound, provided in an earlier comment, to be the function $\  s(1) = 2,\ \  s(2p_{k-1}) = s(2p_k-1) = g(p_{k+1}-1).\  $ This bound is probably an equality until $f(2.19) = f(38) \le g(22) < g(29-1) = s(2.19),\  $ (according to the computations below).

Exploring the effectiveness of the primorial, $g(n-1)$, to cover some sequence of consecutive integers, was provided by a much uglier gcc implementation. Upon reflection, iterating thru all plausible combination of bit strings:

```
101010101010101010...
100100100100100100...
100001000010000100001
1000000100000010000001
10000000000100000000001
...
```

was probably not an efficient idea, but it does test how fast my 22nm processing core can twiddle bits.
$$
\begin{array}{rrlc}
product & = & \ldots & covers \\
1!! = g(1) & f(1) = & f(1) & 1 \\
2!! = g(2) & f(2) = & f(3) & 3 \\
3!! = g(4) & f(4) = & f(5) & 5 \\
4!! = g(6) & f(6) = & f(9) & 9 \\
5!! = g(10) & f(10) = & f(13) & 13 \\
6!! = g(12) & f(14) = & f(21) & 21 \\
7!! = g(16) & f(22) = & f(25) & 25 \\
8!! = g(18) & f(26) = & f(33) & 33 \\
9!! = g(22) & ? & & 39 \\
10!! = g(28) & ? & & 45 \\
11!! = g(30) & ? & & 57 \\
12!! = g(36) & ? & & 65 \end{array}
$$
EDIT: much deeper computations are provided by the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A058989). Because f(n) is monotonically non-decreasing, we can extend $f(26) = f(33) = 2.3.5.7.11.13.17.19,\  $ where $f(26)$ was found with brute force and listed our first table.

Comment: With $n!!$ you mean $p_n\#$?

Comment: @san Yes, I'm referring to the [primorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Primorial.html). Sorry for the abuse of notation.  I appreciate the constructive proof you provided for your bound. I couldn't quite extend it for the special case of twin primes, which sometimes "fall below" your bound.

Comment: @will Despite not getting a complete answer, I decided to award you 50 reputations.  This is a hard problem, and I think you have made a great progress by showing that $f(n)\mid g(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You should put $f(n)$ in the OEIS.

Comment: The first counterexample to $f(k)|f(k+1)$ (and thus the first non-primorial value), will be at 39, 45, 57, 65, 73, 89, 99, 105, 117, 131, 151, 173, 189, 199, 215, 233. I think we would need to calculate this counter example to make $f(n)$ sufficiently distinct from existing entries in the OEIS.

Comment: I just found the relevant paper in http://neumann.math.unideb.hu/~hajdul/jacobsrev.pdf

Comment: According to it, the first counterexample is at $p_{24}$, and $f(n)$ is a primorial for every smaller integer.

Comment: @san Thank you for finding that paper. They use a pair of functions $H$ and $h$ where $h$ measures the cover of the (greedy) primorials, and $H$ measures the cover of the optimal choice of $n$ factors. The greedy choice of $24\#$ is no longer optimal, and table 1 (implicitly) provides exact values for Batominovski's $f(n)$ for all $n \le 235$.

Comment: If someone does add $f(n)$ to OEIS, please increment its value by 1. ($f'(n)$ will find $m$ with a difference of at least $n$, between consecutive coprimes to $m$, ie f(2) = 2, f(4)=6). This will better match the Jacobsthal's [Function](http://oeis.org/A048669) and the work by Hajdu & Saradha.